# Shadows not working correctly for elements on Iphone

Tags: css, webkit, shadow

I'm using several shadows for some elements in css and the problem is that the html pages on mobile devices are not usable at all, and they freeze. Is there any way to fix it?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
.all {
    background:#fff;
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #ccc 0 0 40px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #ccc 0 0 40px;
    box-shadow: #ccc 0 0 40px;
}
```

P.S. Pages load fine at any browser on computer.

Answer (score 1):

It's confirmed issue on iphone/ipad devices with webkit-based browser causing slowdowns and freezes when it re-renders box-shadows on page zooming.

I'd recommend to remove -webkit-box-shadow from css.

Comment: yeah, made me crazy when i was trying to find out what's causing these horrible freezes when i was slicing a mobile website for my customer.